# What happens if two processes call File.read(path) at the same time for the same path in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

If I have two child processes in Ruby, and each calls `File.read()' at the same time (on the same file), what will happen?

What I want to happens is that both processes just read the contents of the file...

Comment: Probably depends on how [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) works on your system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read is a safe operation. You can have however many concurrent readers.

Not so with writes, naturally.

So yeah, what you expect is what will likely happen.